# Does anyone know of any p.r.n.g based on laws that govern fractal geometry?

Tags: random

Are there any prngs or rngs that base their outcome not from random event such as keystrokes or atmospheric conditions but from a set of algorithms based on the laws that produce fractal geometry or an exponential curve.

Comment: Any pseudo-random NG (PRNG) is just some bit-scrambling&shuffling algorithm. Not sure what do you mean about "fractal geometry", but if you're talking about z^2 mapping, it was proposed as PRNG by John von Neumann and proved to be bad one.

Comment: Here is the link to JvN PRNG: https://motherboard.vice.com/en_us/article/wnj48y/how-to-make-a-random-number

Answer (score 0):

The only one I know of is Wolfram's "Rule 30" generator, but not a lot is known about its quality.